# order by XXX sort by ASC or DESC , dynamic ordering, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

I would like to create dynamic sorting for my mysql database results. I currently output the results with a query. I would like to create a 2 links which would sort the results by that selected link, click again and the link ASC or DSEC the results.

I have been searching but am unable to find the right way about doing this.

I even downloaded a framework to see how this is done but no to success.
the example is like follows:

TITLE   TOTAL

As simple as this sounds I am unable to find a dynamic example online.

ANyone else finding google supplies more results to outdated and forums than actual helpful pages?
Even if you sort by last year and relevance.

Comment: Where is your table schema/query? Where is your PHP code?! Show us some code, an attempt of yours, so we can help with where you are stuck at. Do not take us back to our code dreaming...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    // build the basis for the query
    $sql = '
        SELECT 
            `id`,
            `title`,
            `total`
        FROM 
            `my_table`
    ';

    // check for sort field
    $sort_by = isset($_GET['s']) ? $_GET['s'] : false;
    // validate the sort field (avoid Bobby Tables!) and provide default
    switch ($sort_by) {
        case 'title':
        case 'id':
        case 'total':
            break;
        default:
            $sort_by = 'id';
    }

    $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.$sort_by.' ';

    // get the direction, or use the default
    $direction = isset($_GET['d']) ? $_GET['d'] : false;
    if ($direction != 'ASC' && $direction != 'DESC')
        $direction = 'DESC';
    $sql .= $direction;

    // execute query, get results
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $results = array();
    if ($res) {
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $results[] = $r;
        }
    }

    // used in table heading to indicate sort direciton
    $sort_arrow = ($direction == 'ASC' ? '<img src="up_arrow.png" />' : '<img src="down_arrow.png" />');

    // used to build urls to reverse the current sort direction
    $reverse_direction = ($direction == 'DESC' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC');
?>

<table>
    <thead>
        <th scope="col" class="<?php echo $sort_by == 'id' ? 'sortColumn' : ''; ?>">
            <a href="myscript.php?s=id&d=<?php echo $reverse_direction; ?>">ID</a>
            <?php echo $sort_by == 'id' ? $sort_arrow : ''; ?>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="<?php echo $sort_by == 'id' ? 'sortColumn' : ''; ?>">
            <a href="myscript.php?s=title&d=<?php echo $reverse_direction; ?>">Title</a>
            <?php echo $sort_by == 'title' ? $sort_arrow : '';  ?>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="<?php echo $sort_by == 'id' ? 'sortColumn' : ''; ?>">
            <a href="myscript.php?s=total&d=<?php echo $reverse_direction; ?>">Total</a>
            <?php echo $sort_by == 'total' ? $sort_arrow : '';  ?>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            if (count($results) > 0) {
                foreach ($results as $r) {
                    print '<tr>';
                    print '<th scope="row">'.$r['id'].'</th>';
                    print '<td>'.$r['title'].'</td>';
                    print '<td>'.$r['total'].'</td>';
                    print '</tr>';
                }
            } else {
                print '<tr><td colspan=3>No results found</td></tr>';
            }
        ?>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks everyone for your replies, abit more than i expected. So no need for javascript? i thought i would need javascript to order dynamically, Gonna have fiddle with the code you guys supplied, Thanks very much for speedy reply guys.

Comment: It is also possible to do this with javascript via AJAX, however you did not provide enough details about what you already have set up for me to speculate on such an example. Simply put, if you were to use AJAX, you would make an AJAX call to a php script that generated the table HTML only. In the callback for the AJAX request, you would swap out the new HTML for the old. This is, again, a little beyond the scope of this answer given the details we have.

Comment: thanks, no problem, still playing around with code right now. Would you be able to recommend a good source of AJAX reading? People often tell me the W3schools are bad resources.. thanks again for your time.

Comment: w3schools can help you learn like any other resource, just be aware that they aren't "official". They got a bad rap because a couple of guys went on a crusade against them regarding tidbits that don't even really matter to a casual beginner. I wouldn't rely on it as a resource for specs is all, for  introductory examples they are fine. Check out http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ for some more decent tutorials, as well as https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax. The latter link is an excellent resource instead of w3schools - simply put "MDN [thing I am searching for]" into Google to get results.

Comment: hi again, struggling with your code a little, the SortColumn confuses me. I am actually not using a table anymore for the content. sorry am not too up on this coding, back to reading and learning, ill get this working

Comment: This returns no results.
My query is:
SELECT coffeeshops.*, services.*, sum(temp.total) as final_total FROM coffeeshops inner join services on coffeeshops.shop_id=services.shop_id
inner join (select SUM(comfort + service + ambience + friendliness + spacious + experience + bud_quality + bud_price + drink_price + space_cake + accessibility + toilet_access)/(12) /COUNT(shop_id) AS total, shop_id FROM ratings GROUP BY shop_id
) as temp on coffeeshops.shop_id=temp.shop_id 
GROUP BY shop_name

when i reduce it to "SELECT * FROM coffeeshops"   it works, is this something to do with sum or the join?

Comment: Yes, the SUM/JOIN is not correct. You should start a new question for this so there is room to provide more details

Comment: i have managed to get it working by removing the shop_id, works great, thanks very much. Now am trying to get this pagination i had working to work in combination with the sort by asc/desc, one problem after another, back to fiddling around till something works. thanks again Chris

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

    $order = ($_GET['order'] == 'asc') ? 'asc' : 'desc';

    $sql = "SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY TITLE $order";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    ...

     $new_order = ($order == 'asc' ) ? 'desc' : 'asc';
?>

<table>
<thead><tr>
    <th><a href="scriptname.php?order=<?php echo $new_order ?>">TITLE</a></th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr></thead>
etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did it in C#, you can use session instead of viewstate rest of it will be same.

```
if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["sortField"]) == SortExpression){
if (ViewState["sortDir"].ToString() == "ASC")
        { ViewState["sortDir"] = "DESC"; }
    else
        { ViewState["sortDir"] = "ASC"; }
    }
else
{ ViewState["sortDir"] = "ASC"; }
ViewState["sortField"] = SortExpression;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the sort variable from the URL with $_GET['sort'] eg. site.php?sort=ASC and pass it to the query, remember about sanity checks!