# Sort a database row array by row value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here is my PHP script. What I wish to do is to sort the response array by a key. The key that I wish to sort the array by is a component of the row. To better clarify, say the row contained a string and an int type object. How can I sort the array using the int object as key? I have looked at ksort() and understand how to use it but I am unsure how to use it in the way that I am attempting to.

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


$host = "localhost"; //server
$db = "Test"; //database name
$user = "root"; //dabases user name
$pwd = "xxxxxxx"; //password


    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Table");


    // check for empty result
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {

        $response["stuff"] = array();
        $event = "";

         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $event = $row;
            $response[] = event;

         } 

      //Here I wish to sort the array by the int object as key.
     $response["success"] = 1;

    echo json_encode($response);
}
 ?>
```

Comment: you want to sort using PHP? no just sort it thru the query, mysql already has that capability

Comment: chkout this example... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179677/order-by-xxx-sort-by-asc-or-desc-dynamic-ordering-mysql

Comment: @superuserdo sure man no prob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above might answer this specific requirement, but I would like to also describe how to sort a PHP array like the question poster wants to:

The method of choice is not `ksort()` (sort by key), but
[`usort (&$array, $value_compare_func)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) (sort by user-defined callback):

```
usort($response['stuff'], function($a, $b) {
    return $a['integer'] - $b['integer'];
});
```

Where the closure function is a simple integer comparison using array members as operands (with key `integer` in this example).
When comparing other types of values, the comparison function should be adapted to meet the requirements of `usort()`. E.g. for strings, one would use `strcmp()`.