# MYSQL sort by desc or asc

Tags: html

Below is my website I would like to add some sort of image sorter that when a button is clicked will sort the image by asc/desc depending on image date.

Comment: Show us your current code.

Comment: view-source:http://www.nzlocos.com/sasdlast.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't specified your problem, Here is the basic `mysql`code for your problem.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name ASC \ DESC;
```

`ORDER BY` `ASC \ DESC` is responsible for making the order. other things are usual `mysql` elements

Comment: Hi thanks but how could I add the sql into the php code and how would I add buttons to the webpage that activate it? thanks Kieran.

Comment: first you have to create a database connection with PHP & then you can make a variable with this query inside your php. Ex : `$query = "SELECT * FROM admin ";` and then you can execute it like this `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);` I advice you to reffer http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: Would you mind remote controlling my pc to help me please.

Comment: sorry @KieranRead - you have to proceed it. we are very much busy with works. Surely there are many supportive tutorials in the internet.

Comment: Sorry but im really useless with php and sql so I have to add the php code to connect sweet. But what about the two buttons that activate it and the sql code doesnt work.

Comment: If you have done something (any coding), Put the code as another question. so it would be easier to figure out your situation & the fault. Unless it is very much difficult. here are people specialized in PHP they will surely help you. post your code in a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179677/order-by-xxx-sort-by-asc-or-desc-dynamic-ordering-mysql?rq=1 this also seems to be simillar to your problem